# Laravel 5 Eloquent Many to Many 2ndary table

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5.1, mariadb

I have a question that I'm not sure how to solve or even phrase for finding an answer.

I have a Company Model & User Model that are related Many-to-Many.

I want to have a user_pins table. A user can belong to multiple companies and therefore have a different pin within each company. The pin is unique within a company, no two users within a company can have the same one. Users in different companies can have the same one.

So for the company it is One to Many, for the user it is One to Many, but altogether it is many to many, Im not sure if that makes sense.

I have the table set up as

```
Schema::create('user_pins', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
 $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
 $table->string('pin');

 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
 $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

 $table->primary(['user_id', 'company_id', 'pin']);
});
```

How do I relate this table in the models and use Eloquent to access/create/update it so it stores both the user and company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would change the name to `company_user` so that it follows the same naming convention that Laravel would use out of the box. (you wouldn't have to do this as you can specify the pivot table name in the relationship but if there isn't a reason to stick with `user_pin` it makes sence to follow convention :) )

Then I would remove the primary key from being a compound of all 3 fields and just have it on the `company_id` and `user_id`.

Lastly, as a PIN only has to be unique for a company, I would just put the unique index on those two columns e.g.

```
Schema::create('company_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('pin');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['company_id', 'user_id']);
    $table->unique(['company_id', 'pin']);
});
```

Then for the relationship in the model I would have something like:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company')->withPivot('pin');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('pin');
```

**Examples of use with pivot**

All user pins for a company:

```
$company->users->lists('pivot.pin');
```

Users pin for a specific company

```
$user->companies()->where('id', $id)->get()->pivot->pin;
```

Users pin for the first company relationship:

```
$user->companies->first()->pivot->pin;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the company_user table is already used on my many to many relationship with the companies & users tables. Are you saying I should just add a field on that pivot table for the pin?

Comment: In that case, yeah, you might as well. Just remember to add the composite unique index for the `company_id` and `pin`.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I access the pin through the company and user models.

For instance if I wanted to get all the user pins through the company model or just a users pin for a given company through the user model?

Comment: I've added a few examples to my answer.

Comment: Excellent, this definitely solves my conundrum. It makes sense to have it on the pivot table, I just thought it was strictly for the many to many relationship and didn't have extra fields.